# I want to update next month employee salary table to current table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have current salary table callsed jan, columns are employeename, employeeid and Jansalary. I have to update Feb salary to January table. my code is:

```
update jan 
set jan.salary=feb.salary

from jan
inner join feb
on feb.employeeid=jan.employeeid
```

my question is if feb have new employee salary data, should I use right join?

Comment: First of all, it's a terrible database design. Secondly, you're overwriting January with February data. And third, depending on the actual data INNER JOIN might not be right at all.

Comment: My purpose is to overwrite the January data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is incorrect you can not put UPDATE after FROM it will gives you syntax incorrect.

The correct query is something like this :

```
update jan, feb
set jan.salary=feb.salary
where feb.employeeid=jan.employeeid;
```

If you have a new employee salary data on Feb you have two options :

**Option 1 :** You dont want to have the new employee salary data on Jan so in this case nothing to do because your join is based on employeeid
**Option 2 :** You want to replicate the new employee salary data on Jan so this query can do this :

```
INSERT INTO `feb` (`employeeid`,`employeename`,`salary`)
SELECT DISTINCT(feb.employeeid), employeename, salary
FROM feb
WHERE feb.employeeid NOT IN (SELECT jan.employeeid FROM jan);
```

Your design is bad the best is just to create one table called `salary` and you put the month as filed on this table :

**salary table**

1. employeeid
2. salary_amount
3. month

Comment: Thank you Farouk. Really appreciate it